# Saving transaction ids of failed responses while running the JMeter load test in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

There is a Jmeter load test which we would like to run in Jenkins and it will be run for a long time, say 2 hours. I want to capture the transaction ids of all the failed responses and give it to the dev. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever "transaction id" is it should be possible to save it using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), example code:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    vars.put('failedTransactionId', 'your-transaction-id-here')
}
```

Once done you can add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

```
sample_variables=failedTransactionId
```

and next time you run your test JMeter will create a new column in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) with the value of the failed transaction ID for each failed Sampler.

If you cannot modify user.properties file you [can set this `sample_variables` property value via `-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=failedTransactionId -n -t test.jmx ....
```